# How to add user at once in all databases?(Sybase-ASE)

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I want to add a user to all databases with the following command `sp_adduser`  at once to all databases. What query can give access to all databases at once?
Is this generally possible to do in the Sybase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work from the shell script:

```
user=<your new sybase user>

isql -U ${UID} -P ${PWD} -S ${SERVER} <<! | tee $0.out
set nocount on
go
declare cur cursor for select name from master..sysdatabases order by 1
go
declare @l_name varchar(30), @l_sql varchar(777)
begin
  open cur
  fetch cur into @l_name
  while @@sqlstatus = 0
  begin
    print @l_name 
    fetch cur into @l_name
  end
  close cur
  deallocate cur
end  
go
!

for dbname in `cat ${0}.out`; do
  echo "
use ${dbname}
go
sp_adduser ${user}
go
" >>${0}.sql
done

isql -U ${UID} -P ${PWD} -S ${SERVER} -i ${0}.sql
```

Comment: Why are you using a cursor just to get a list of database names when a straight select would do?

Comment: Earlier version attempted execute immediate, which does not take sp_adduser.

Comment: Thats fine you still don't need a cursor to get the names into a file though without the execute immediate. You can also exec dbname..sp_adduser rather than use the db each time and that will work.